# одномерный массив пользователей в оргструктуру

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

У меня есть одномерный массив сущностей вида

```
[
  {
    id: number
    parentId: number
    type: string
    name: string
  }
]
```

Хочу разложить его в оргструктуру в Реакте, т.о. чтобы элементы у которых parentId совпадает с id другого элемента в разметке стали бы его потомками. Максимальная глубина структуры - 4. Я пробовал раскладывать со вложенными массивами в каждом элементе в поле `children` -- в принципе все работает, вот только мы имеем сложность `n^4`. Сруктура должна быть по итогу что-то типа такого:

```
<div id="1" class="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="2" parent-id="1" class="wrapper">
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="3" parent-id="1" class="wrapper">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="4" parent-id="3" class="wrapper">
                    <div class="item"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Пример массива:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parentId": 0,
    "type": "main",
    "name": "Генеральный директор"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "parentId": 1,
    "type": "section",
    "name": "Отдел найма"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "parentId": 1,
    "type": "section",
    "name": "Отдел обучения"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "parentId": 1,
    "type": "section",
    "name": "Отдел создания контента"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "parentId": 3,
    "type": "section",
    "name": "Отдел создания контента"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "parentId": 5,
    "type": "section",
    "name": "Отдел создания контента"
  }
]
```

Comment: Если не нужно чтобы структура была сразу раскрыта я бы делал это динамически т.е. добавление дочернего элемента только при раскрытии. Файловый менеджер работает подобным образом

Comment: @DaniilLoban не, в данном случае она должна быть вся видна сразу

Comment: В таком случае я бы не обращал внимание на n^4, а оптимизацию приложил к видимым данным ( экранам, lazyloading) потому что 1000 записей не влезет в экран

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Сруктура должна быть по итогу что-то типа такого:

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
//
function Row({id = 0}) {
  if (!arr.some(o => o.parentId === id)) return null
  return <div className="row">
    <App id={id} />
  </div>
}
//
function App({id = 0}) {
  return <React.Fragment>
    {arr.filter(o => o.parentId === id).map(o => {
      if (id) return <div key={o.id} id={o.id} parent-id={id} className="wrapper">
        <div className="item">{o.name}</div>
        <Row id={o.id} />
      </div>
      return <div key={o.id} id={o.id} className="wrapper">
        <div className="item">{o.name}</div>
        <Row id={o.id} />
      </div>
    })}
  </React.Fragment>
}
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parentId": 0,
    "type": "main",
    "name": "Генеральный директор"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "parentId": 1,
    "type": "section",
    "name": "Отдел найма"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "parentId": 1,
    "type": "section",
    "name": "Отдел обучения"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "parentId": 1,
    "type": "section",
    "name": "Отдел создания контента 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "parentId": 3,
    "type": "section",
    "name": "Отдел создания контента 3"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "parentId": 5,
    "type": "section",
    "name": "Отдел создания контента 5"
  }
]
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```css
.row {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```